# Environment variable in a thread context

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix

I have a program, lets call it scheduler, which spawns 2 threads using openmp on a for loop. Something like this:

```
#pragma omp for num_threads(2)
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    if (omp_get_thread() == 0)
        setenv("VAR", 0);
    else
        setenv("VAR", 1);

    system("./script.sh");
}
```

The script execution will depend on that VAR value. How can I make the context of VAR in thread 0 different from thread 1 so that they can keep different values?

Comment: what is the use case for this, you want to use environment variables which will be global to both those threads. Why not set a global variable for each thread, or set a local variable and have that influence the environment variable value.

Comment: If the purpose of setting `VAR` is that to modify the behaviour of script.sh, then why don't you just pass `VAR` as a regular command line argument?

Comment: I simplified the problem. Each script call will execute an application which uses openmp too. I want to define the GOMP_CPU_BIND variable individually for each of those applications, since there is not a way that I know to do it hardcoded

Comment: This can't really be done the way you are trying to do it. In this case, the Environment that both threads are running in is the same executable, and thus they'll have the same environment. As smani said, its better to pass the argument into the script...or use a smarter process launcher.

Comment: Environment variables are associated with a *process*, not a *thread* (which a process can have several of). If you must use environment variables then you'll probably need something along the lines of `system("bash -c \"VAR=1; ./script.sh\"")`... Otherwise, using `setenv()` in separate threads is going to be racy or worse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, unless there are real reasons, I'd write the scheduler in shell or some other scripting language. Using openmp is an overkill, the fork control operator `&` should work just fine.

Secondly, every shell has its own environment (which child processes inherit), so I'd just pass the desired value of  `GOMP_CPU_BIND` (actually, you probably mean `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` since the former does not appear to be documented anywhere?) as a command line argument to `script.sh` and then export `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` in `script.sh` with the corresponding value.

So to sum it up, you'd write something like:

**scheduler.sh:**

```
 #!/bin/sh
 ./script.sh 1 &
 ./script.sh 2 &
```

**script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=$1
./myprog
```